# For each $k$ there exists $m$ s.t. $x+s(x)=m$ has exactly $k$ solutions in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I wanted to solve this olympiad problem from 2003 found here: https://imomath.com/othercomp/Rom/RomTST03.pdf

> Let $s(n)$ denote the sum of decimal digits of a positive integer $n$. Prove that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a positive integer $m$ such that the equation $x+s(x)=m$ has exactly $k$ solutions in $\mathbb{N}$.

Of course
$$
x+s(x)\equiv 2x \equiv m \pmod{9}
$$
has to have $k$ solutions, but for $m=1,2,...,8$ there are always infinitely many solutions of the form $x=a+9b$. How can I construct a number $m$ such that the equation has $k$ solutions?

Comment: In first sentence $s(n)$ defined, but question in second sentence refers to $d(x).$

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%2Bs(x)%3Dm%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Adecimal%20digits%2C%20OR%20content%3Asum&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [For n the sum of digits =d(n), then x+d(x)=m has k solutions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h53285p334405). Note that post #$4$ has a link to a PDF file of the official solution, while post #$7$ has a link to an answer in Chinese.

Comment: Thanks, then my question is answered!